# How to stop Portrait Images being truncated using jQuery Cycle Lite Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using the following
Wordpress 3.1.1 with Nextgen Gallery and the JQuery Cycle Lite plugin.
I have downloaded the latest version of the Cycle Lite Plug in from http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/lite/

The problem I have is the Gallery I am using has some portrait images in and although I have fit set they are being chopped off rather than shrunk.  See http://www.rjt.org.uk/home/testlocation1

I am using [jj-ngg-jquery-cycle html_id="about-cycle-lite" gallery="7" width="400" height="600" fit="0" center="1"] in Wordpress.

I suspect the problem is with the following section,  but am not sure how to fix it.

```
        $slides.each(function() {
        var $el = $(this);
        this.cycleH = (opts.fit && opts.height) ? opts.height : $el.height();
        this.cycleW = (opts.fit && opts.width) ? opts.width : $el.width();
    });
```

Suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example page has an exception: `jQuery("div#about-cycle-lite").jjcycle is not a function`

I've created a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8zeDs/) but all the images are the same size in your example there are none taller.

Comment: Thanks for that, but it's distorting the images, any idea's on how to keep the aspect ratio?

Comment: There is a fork of cycle that has added support for that https://github.com/malsup/cycle/pull/42

Comment: Thanks for finding that Daniel,  I will see if I can add that code into my copy and see it that fixes the problem later today.